# rotate background image from rotated div

Tags: css, rotation

I have added a background image to a div, but because the div has been rotated, so has the background-image. How can I rotate just the image the opposite way to it appears straight?

live url: http://bit.ly/1iqXQRN

html

```
<section id="about-hero-img"></section>
```

css

```
#about-hero-img {
-webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
transform: rotate(-2deg);
width: 1030px; margin-left: -50px; margin-top: 20px; height: 200px; background-image: url('../Images/about-header-img.jpg'); padding-top: 30px; }
```

Comment: you can check this example, gives a real solution for your problem. http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-transform-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

Move the background-image to a the :before pseudo-element of you header

```
#about-hero-img {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-2deg);
    transform: rotate(-2deg);
    width: 1030px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    height: 200px;
    /* background-image: url('../Images/about-header-img.jpg'); */
    padding-top: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
#about-hero-img:before {
    width: 1030px;
    height: 230px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    content: ' ';
    background-image: url('../Images/about-header-img.jpg');
    -webkit-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(2deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(2deg);
    transform: rotate(2deg);
}
```